# Sentence structure in english?

Tags: grammar

I see a sentence: "The department-wide (Noun) changes (V) suggested (?) by (Preposition) Ms. Juntasa received unanimous approval from company management.". What type of word "suggested"? If it is Adj, why don't have one noun after it?

Comment: Not all adjectives have a noun after them; predicative adjectives generally don’t.

Comment: Your parsing has significant errors: *department-wide* is an adjective, not a noun; *changes* is a noun, not a verb. NB: this site is for "serious English language enthusiasts"; you might find our other site [ell.se] much more appropriate. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The department-wide (Adj) changes (N) suggested (V) by (Preposition) Ms. Juntasa received (main V of the whole sentence) unanimous approval from company management."

Answer (score 0):

"Department-wide" is (acting as) an adjective.  "Changes" is a plural noun.  "Suggested" is the past participle of the verb "suggest".

Comment: _Suggested_ is not a verb in the past tense, but a past participle. It’s a reduced relative clause, “changes [which were] suggested”.